# How does MetaMask confirm the trasaction? The workflow of metamask

Tags: metamask, golang

I'm trying to make interaction between my customized chain and Metamask.
Network is added, and token sending is successful on chain side. But in MM, tx state is still pending. how can I fix that? What's wrong with response from chain?
These are the log from the chain. All the requests are from Metamask.

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
"result": "0x08CAD917F37470A1A716316848323134A3498B731CCCCC9ABC59345DB3C6CAC6"

eth_getTransactionReceipt
"result": {
  "blockHash": "0x5DB6FE8065595FE74BA236445D79B2F6E31B1ABC903E1D2027EC0EF65769CD77",
  "blockNumber": "0xfd82",
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": "0xa12515",
  "effectiveGasPrice": "0x5a9c688d4",
  "from": "0x8d133c22a7f4054e7adefb6c4df96d6d6763da0c",
  "gasUsed": "0xb4c8",
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": "0x1",
  "to": "0xf1829676db577682e944fc3493d451b67ff3e29f",
  "transactionHash": "0x08CAD917F37470A1A716316848323134A3498B731CCCCC9ABC59345DB3C6CAC6",
  "transactionIndex": "0x0",
  "type": "0x2"
}

eth_getBlockByHash
"result": {
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x737061726b706f6f6c2d636e2d6e6f64652d3132",
  "gasLimit": "0x1c9c380",
  "gasUsed": "0x79ccd3",
  "hash": "0x5DB6FE8065595FE74BA236445D79B2F6E31B1ABC903E1D2027EC0EF65769CD77",
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "miner": "0x841E7206A23609034C1CA3A888DD591AB687F0B1",
  "number": "0xfd82",
  "parentHash": "0x0c5f3ae400b9f76df5176f3ce35d3c17de75df7d76f43001e80ec2e00145041db6085140d390c1e7917c002e8403af77",
  "receiptsRoot": "0x6CDF9EDB097AD6014C75C865283D93796965FEB3169B8C5C2F5C93FBC3F1E80E",
  "sha3Uncles": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "size": "0x41c7",
  "stateRoot": "0xddc8b0234c2e0cad087c8b389aa7ef01f7d79b2570bccb77ce48648aa61c904d",
  "timestamp": "0x18c5b89c195",
  "totalDifficulty": "0x12ac11391a2f3872fcd",
  "transactions": [
    "0x08cad917f37470a1a716316848323134a3498b731ccccc9abc59345db3c6cac6"
  ],
  "transactionsRoot": "0x6CDF9EDB097AD6014C75C865283D93796965FEB3169B8C5C2F5C93FBC3F1E80E",
  "uncles": []
}
```

Comment: What type of blockchain are you developing? PoA, PoS, PoW, etc. Is it minting more block?

Comment: POS, it was mining. It's fixed now. I don't know how I solved. Just modified gas price, gas fee... etc. Modified chain params.